# Set DeliveryName and DeliveryAddress in a Sales Order (Header and Lines) AX 2012 r2

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, ecommerce-sales

I'm having trouble setting `deliveryName` and `deliveryAddress` from a sales order  by X++ code.
(`SalesTable` and `SalesLine`) in AX 2012.

This piece of code will add an address to a sales order but it links that address to a customer like a customer address, and than put the result on these 2 fields.

But if I create manually a delivery address from the "+" button inside a Sales Order, it does another behavior.   It doesn't link the address to the customer but instead to the sales Order, how do I modify my code to behave this way?

```
lpaView.initValue();
lpaView.Street = this.getOleDBString(oleDbDataReader, #PT_DLVSTREET);
lpaView.County = this.getOleDBString(oleDbDataReader, #PT_DLVCITY);
lpaView.State = this.getOleDBString(oleDbDataReader, #PT_DLVCOUNTY);
lpaView.CountryRegionId = this.getOleDBString(oleDbDataReader, #PT_DLVSTATE);
lpaView.ZipCode = this.getOleDBString(oleDbDataReader, #PT_DLVZIPCODE);

roleContainer = [LogisticsLocationRole::findBytype(LogisticsLocationRoleType::Delivery).RecId];

if (lpaView.Street || lpaView.City || lpaView.State || lpaView.County || lpaView.ZipCode)
{
    if (lpaView.County)
    {
        logisticsAddressCounty = LogisticsAddressCounty::findCountyCode(lpaView.CountryRegionId, lpaView.County);
        if (logisticsAddressCounty)
            lpaView.State = logisticsAddressCounty.StateId;
    }
    hasAddress = true;

    dirParty =  DirParty::constructFromPartyRecId(DirPartyTable::findRec(CustTable::find(salesTable.CustAccount).Party).RecId);
    lpaView.Location = this.getLocationRecId(CustTable::find(salesTable.CustAccount).Party).RecId, conPeek(roleContainer, 1), lpaView.LocationName);

    dirParty.createOrUpdatePostalAddress(lpaView);
    addressLocation = this.getLogisticsLocationAddress(DirPartyTable::findRec(CustTable::find(salesTable.CustAccount).Party).RecId);
    logisticsLocation.clear();
    logisticsLocation.IsPostalAddress = NoYes::No;
    logisticsLocation.ParentLocation = addressLocation.RecId;
    logisticsLocation.insert();

    logisticsElectronicAddress.clear();
    logisticsElectronicAddress.Location = logisticsLocation.RecId;
    logisticsElectronicAddress.insert();

    select logisticsLocationExt where logisticsLocationExt.Location == addresslocation.RecId;
    if (!logisticsLocationExt)
    {
        logisticsLocationExt.clear();
        logisticsLocationExt.Location = addresslocation.RecId;
        logisticsLocationExt.insert();
    }

    postalAddress = LogisticsPostalAddress::findByLocation(logisticsLocation.ParentLocation);
}
salesTable.DeliveryPostalAddress = postalAddress.RecId;
```

zfds

Answer (score 0):

You have to set in you code the method InitFromCustTable(), that will do the order sales take the delivery address.